# How can I remove the citation in stargazer?

Tags: r, stargazer

I am using stargazer to output regresson tables in R. However, at the start of each table, the output says

```
% Table created by stargazer v.5.2.2 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University.  
E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu  
% Date and time: Sat, Dec 19, 2020 - 14:45:37
```

Is it possible to get rid of this?

Comment: If I run `stargazer::stargazer(lm(mpg ~ am + hp, data=mtcars), type='html')` I am not getting anything like that. what you are running here , can you share your code? (This is just a dummy example, not meant to be used). the point is that I am not getting the citation part

Comment: ```{r, results='asis'}
stargazer(attitude)
```

Comment: If I run that and knit it to a pdf it comes up

Comment: @Megan When you call `stargazer` function add `header = FALSE` to it:  `stargazer(attitude, header = FALSE)`

Comment: That worked, thank!

Answer (score 2):

This is quite easy to fix!

Try the following:

````
```{r, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, results = 'asis'}

library(stargazer)

linear <- lm(x ~ y)
stargazer(linear, header = FALSE)

```
````

The linear model is just for the sake of illustration.